# Привязка canvas в пространстве?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Делаю приложение для Hololens. Есть canvas с кнопками и текстом, мне нужно сделать так, что бы его можно было перемещать в пространстве и изменять его размер. Возможно ли это сделать или есть другой способ?

Comment: Возможно,только надо canvas к какому-нибудь объекту прикрепить. Я так хитбоксы делал,если правильно понял пример.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто поставьте у канвы свойство `render mode - world space` и она появится в сцене как отдельный объект с со своим `3d transform`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот что это дает:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

PS: правильная подсказка из комментов: для таких канв лучше всегда указывать камеру явно.

Comment: Кстати, https://unity3d.com/ru/how-to/unity-ui-optimization-tips
Здесь написано, почему не следует оставлять пустым Event Camera у таких канвасов (ухудшится производительность)